# Very confused about XCode 4 (after upgrading from 3.x)

Tags: xcode, ios4

My world was perfect when I had XCode version 3.x (3.1 or 3.2?).
Then one day, after upgrading my iPhone device to ios 4, i tried to deploy an app to my device. For some reason I thought that i needed XCode 4 (or SDK 4) in order to deploy directly to an ios 4.0 device (via xcode) because it was giving me an error(s) i've never seen before that seemed it was suggesting I upgrade XCode/SDK.

So now i have XCode 4.0 installed (build 4A304a) and am in a situation where I can't build my code, things are breaking left and right, and on top of it all I have to learn XCode all over again!!

Now here are my questions:

A) Do I need XCode 4 (and/or SDK 4) in order to deploy directly to an ios 4 device?

B) Do I have the right version of XCode?

C) I think there is a new Xcode version out, 4.02 or something. Should I get that right away?

D) Every time I download a new XCode, does it install "next" to the previous XCode versions? (it is a completely new XCode installation or does it upgrade any existing versions?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your questions in order:

> A) Do I need XCode 4 (and/or SDK 4) in
>   order to deploy directly to an ios 4
>   device?

No, you can happily use Xcode 3.x to deploy to an iOS 4.x device. That said, if you want to develop using SDK features that are only present in SDK 4.3 or greater, you'll need to use Xcode 4.x as Xcode 3.x is only available as a package with version 4.2 of the SDK.

> B) Do I have the right version of
>   XCode?

Being realistic, you'll need to move to using Xcode 4.x at some point, so you might as well bite the bullet now and get used to the new environment. Whilst it might take a while, it's worth the transition. (IMHO.) :-)

> C) I think there is a new Xcode
>   version out, 4.02 or something. Should
>   I get that right away?

As Xcode 4.x is still fairly new they're patching it quite frequently. As such, if bandwidth isn't an issue, you might as well stay on top of Xcode releases. That said, unless you encounter a bug that's specific to a release, there's no requirement for you to do this.

> D) Every time I download a new XCode,
>   does it install "next" to the previous
>   XCode versions? (it is a completely
>   new XCode installation or does it
>   upgrade any existing versions?)

By default Xcode will install over any existing versions. However, you can select a different destination during the install process if you want to run multiple versions in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Xcode 4 is indeed disruptive, luckily Apple doesn't do that too often. My experience with Apple technology is that you better go with the latest.

Personally: It took me 3 weeks to become break even in productivity. Now I'm more productive.

A: dunno, probably
B: yes
C: yes
D: in apple's tradition: it overwrites

Comment: Three *weeks*? Think I was pretty much up to speed after about three (admittedly quite painful) hours, although quite a bit of coffee was involved. Then again, I still occasionally fumble for one of the old keyboard shortcuts. :-)

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts, easy switch between debug vs release builds, lack of table of contents in help viewer (still slowing me down), full-screen-greedy layout tougher to debug with simulator side by side, show build result in finder, ... (but 3w probably exagerated)